# Optimize stored procedure query

Tags: firebird

I have 2 tables in a Firebird 2.5 db:

```
SL_SPORS
-----------------
ID_PERS  ID_SUMSP
   10     2
   10     3
   11     2
   

SL_BRUTS
----------------------------------------
ID_PERS  S_SPORS_1  S_SPORS_2  S_SPORS_3 ...
   10     0            50         0
   11     0             0         0
```

I need to get ID_PERS and ID_SUMSP from first table where  S_SPORS_[ID_SUMSP] is 0 in second table,ID_SUMSP is from 1 to 7,in SL_BRUTS there is only one record for a person

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_VALIDSUM()
 RETURNS (RES VARCHAR(500)) AS
 ....
 FOR SELECT A.ID_PERS,S.ID_SUMSP FROM SL_SPORS INTO :ID_PERS,:ID_SUMSP DO
  BEGIN
    SUMA=0;
   EXECUTE STATEMENT 'SELECT FIRST 1 S_SPORS_'||:ID_SUMSP||' FROM SL_BRUTS WHERE ID_PERS='||:ID_PERS INTO :SUMA;
  IF (SUMA=0) THEN
   BEGIN
    RES='SUM 0 FOR ID_PERS='||:ID_PERS||' AND ID_SUMSP='||:ID_SUMSP;" 
    SUSPEND;
   END
 END
```

it is working but I want to know if there is a better solution,for example maybe I can load all ID_SUMSP from first table in single query using LIST(..)..or I can check all 1-7 fields from table 2 on a single query

Comment: "better" in what way? is it slow? does it use too much RAM? how slow / how much? explain the hardware it's running on, the performance it currently has, and what you want instead. show the table schemas and execution plans.

Comment: ok,I've edit the question and added details

Comment: you have to change structure (Schema) of the second table - read Grubber's "Essential SQL" or any other tutorial on "database normalization".  `SL_BRUTS` table should be re-molded to have three columns: `ID_PERS` and `ID_SUMSP` and `S_SPORS`.

Comment: How many different S_SPORS_nnn columns are there in table SL_BRUTS? If it is not too many, you can probably transform this N+1 query problem to a single query, where you unpivot those columns using repeated UNION ALL, and then join against the resulting derived table.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: there are 1 to 7 S_SPORS_nnn

Comment: @mrapi puzzling: a table can only have some fixed number of columns, it can be 1 it can be 7 but not "1 to 7"

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the structure (Schema) of the second table - read Martin Gruber's "Essential SQL" or any other tutorial on "database normalization". SL_BRUTS table should be re-molded to have three columns: ID_PERS and ID_SUMSP and S_SPORS

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Do one-time data conversion and then do your queries over normalized tables. The structure you made in SL_BRUTS would never allow you any efficient queries but most trivial.

Check the QUERY EXECUTION PLAN in the last two queries below:

> ```
> select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version
>      , rdb$character_set_name
> from rdb$database;
> ```
>
> ```
> VERSION | RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME                                                                                                      
> :------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 3.0.5   | UTF8
> ```

> ```
> create table SL_SPORS (
>   ID_PERS  integer,
>   ID_SPORS integer,
>   Primary key (ID_PERS, ID_SPORS)
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into SL_SPORS 
> select 10, 2 from rdb$database union all
> select 10, 3 from rdb$database union all
> select 11, 2 from rdb$database union all
> select 20, 3 from rdb$database
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from sl_spors
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_PERS | ID_SPORS
> ------: | -------:
>      10 |        2
>      10 |        3
>      11 |        2
>      20 |        3
> ```

> ```
> -- CAN this sl_spors_NNN data be NULL ? or not ? what is semantics, what is meaning of it???
> create table SL_BROKEN (
>   ID_PERS  integer primary key,
>   s_SPORS_1 integer NOT NULL,  
>   s_SPORS_2 integer NOT NULL,
>   s_SPORS_3 integer NOT NULL
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table SL_RAWS (
>   ID_PERS  integer,
>   ID_SPORS integer,
>   S_SPOR integer NOT NULL,
>   Primary key (ID_PERS, ID_SPORS),
>   constraint impossible_over_SL_BROKEN 
>      FOREIGN KEY(ID_PERS, ID_SPORS)
>      REFERENCES SL_SPORS(ID_PERS, ID_SPORS)
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- should throw error over non-existing PERSON - but would it ???
> insert into SL_BROKEN
> values (-100, 20, 30, 40)
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> -- should throw error over non-existing PERSON - and it would!
> insert into SL_RAWS
> values (-100, 20, 30)
> ```

violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "IMPOSSIBLE_OVER_SL_BROKEN" on table "SL_RAWS" Foreign key reference target does not exist Problematic key value is ("ID_PERS" = -100, "ID_SPORS" = 20)

> 

> ```
> insert into  SL_BROKEN 
> select 10, 0, 50, 0 from rdb$database union all
> select 11, 0,  0, 0 from rdb$database
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from SL_BROKEN
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_PERS | S_SPORS_1 | S_SPORS_2 | S_SPORS_3
> ------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
>    -100 |        20 |        30 |        40
>      10 |         0 |        50 |         0
>      11 |         0 |         0 |         0
> ```

> ```
> delete from SL_BROKEN where ID_PERS < 0
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> create view SL_TRANSPOSE as
> SELECT 1 as ID_SPORS, ID_PERS, S_SPORS_1 as S_SPOR from SL_BROKEN  
>   union all
> SELECT 2 as ID_SPORS, ID_PERS, S_SPORS_2 as S_SPOR from SL_BROKEN  
>   union all
> SELECT 3 as ID_SPORS, ID_PERS, S_SPORS_3 as S_SPOR from SL_BROKEN
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from SL_TRANSPOSE
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_SPORS | ID_PERS | S_SPOR
> -------: | ------: | -----:
>        1 |      10 |      0
>        1 |      11 |      0
>        2 |      10 |     50
>        2 |      11 |      0
>        3 |      10 |      0
>        3 |      11 |      0
> ```

> ```
> insert into SL_RAWS (ID_PERS, ID_SPORS, S_SPOR)
> select ID_PERS, ID_SPORS, S_SPOR from SL_TRANSPOSE
> ```

violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "IMPOSSIBLE_OVER_SL_BROKEN" on table "SL_RAWS" Foreign key reference target does not exist Problematic key value is ("ID_PERS" = 10, "ID_SPORS" = 1)

> 

> ```
> insert into SL_SPORS 
> select 10, 1 from rdb$database union all
> select 11, 3 from rdb$database union all
> select 11, 1 from rdb$database
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> insert into SL_RAWS (ID_PERS, ID_SPORS, S_SPOR)
> select ID_PERS, ID_SPORS, S_SPOR from SL_TRANSPOSE
> ```

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from SL_RAWS
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_PERS | ID_SPORS | S_SPOR
> ------: | -------: | -----:
>      10 |        1 |      0
>      11 |        1 |      0
>      10 |        2 |     50
>      11 |        2 |      0
>      10 |        3 |      0
>      11 |        3 |      0
> ```

> ```
> select * from SL_RAWS where S_SPOR = 0  -- where S_SPOR IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_PERS | ID_SPORS | S_SPOR
> ------: | -------: | -----:
>      10 |        1 |      0
>      11 |        1 |      0
>      11 |        2 |      0
>      10 |        3 |      0
>      11 |        3 |      0
> ```

> ```
> select * from SL_TRANSPOSE where S_SPOR = 0  -- where S_SPOR IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_SPORS | ID_PERS | S_SPOR
> -------: | ------: | -----:
>        1 |      10 |      0
>        1 |      11 |      0
>        2 |      11 |      0
>        3 |      10 |      0
>        3 |      11 |      0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=c43c69206fc3665beb7cf0e0c66d58b6)*

Comment: thanks for your answer,I can't change the table structure

Comment: @mrapi then i suggest you to make your own intermediate table, keep it populated with up to date data from the source table and work with that normal one instead. With the... perplexed structure of that source table there would be no efficient queries over it. So, instead of paying penalties on every query it might have sense to pay them once (on data conversion) then making efficient queries over normalized table further on.